# How to handle the conflict in multiple autoloaders

Tags: php, autoload

I am using  **_*autoload***  in my system, and I need to import a library that has alot of classes, it uses **_autoload** function to auto-load its classes.

 
unfortunately once I call this library the code is calling my classes with a wrong path.

```
  does anyone have any idea how can i solve this issue?
```

Comment: did you try registering your autoloader function only for your namespaces? http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: no i didn't can you please give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, you could just register your autoload function especially for your namespace. Taken [from the php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), here is one example:

```
<?php

namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    static public function test($name) {
        print '[['. $name .']]';
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::test'); // As of PHP 5.3.0
new InexistentClass;
```

Read up on [PHP Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) to fully understand how this works.